# The specified child already has a parent.

Tags: android

I have a problem when creating a dynamic view, the first time the user presses the floating button the layout is displayed but when it is pressed a second time an error in the Logcat is displayed and the app halts.

Code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

import android.text.Layout;
import android.util.Log;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class tabTueActivity extends Fragment {

    int i;

    LinearLayout layoutNewEvent, linearLayoutEventText, linearLayoutEventVoyage, linearLayoutEventIndicator, eventLayout;

    ImageView imageViewEventFrom, imageViewEventTo, imageViewSearch;

    TextView textViewEventFrom, textViewEventTo;

    FloatingActionButton createEvent;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_tue_frag, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(final View rootView, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(rootView, savedInstanceState);

        eventLayout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.event_layout);
        createEvent = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.add_event_button);

        final LinearLayout layoutNewEvent = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        final LinearLayout linearLayoutEventText = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        final LinearLayout linearLayoutEventIndicator = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        final LinearLayout linearLayoutEventVoyage = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        final ImageView imageViewEventFrom = new ImageView(getActivity());
        final ImageView imageViewEventTo = new ImageView(getActivity());
        final ImageView imageViewSearch = new ImageView(getActivity());
        final TextView textViewEventTo = new TextView(getActivity());
        final TextView textViewEventFrom = new TextView(getActivity());

        final   LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutNewEventParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                layoutNewEventParams.setMargins(40, 40, 40, 40);
                layoutNewEventParams.height = 140;

        final   LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearLayoutEventTextParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        final   LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearLayoutEventIndicatorParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        final   LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageViewEventFromParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                imageViewEventFromParams.setMargins(0,0,0,10);
                imageViewEventFromParams.weight = (float) 0.5;

        final   LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageViewEventToParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                imageViewEventToParams.weight = (float) 0.5;


        createEvent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                i++;

                Log.e("EVENT BUTTON", "New event created.....");

                layoutNewEvent.setId(i);
                layoutNewEvent.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.eventColor));
                layoutNewEvent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

                linearLayoutEventText.setId(i);
                linearLayoutEventText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        Log.e("LAYOUT EVENT","Layout Event Pressed.....");

                    }
                });

                linearLayoutEventText.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                linearLayoutEventText.setLayoutParams(linearLayoutEventTextParams);

                linearLayoutEventIndicator.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                linearLayoutEventIndicator.setLayoutParams(linearLayoutEventIndicatorParams);

                imageViewEventFrom.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.backgroundColor3));
                imageViewEventFrom.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageViewEventFrom.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_up_white);
                imageViewEventFrom.setLayoutParams(imageViewEventFromParams);

                imageViewEventTo.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.backgroundColor2));
                imageViewEventTo.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageViewEventTo.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_down_white);
                imageViewEventTo.setLayoutParams(imageViewEventToParams);

                linearLayoutEventIndicator.addView(imageViewEventFrom);
                linearLayoutEventIndicator.addView(imageViewEventTo);
                linearLayoutEventText.addView(linearLayoutEventIndicator);
                layoutNewEvent.addView(linearLayoutEventText);
                eventLayout.addView(layoutNewEvent, layoutNewEventParams);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

I know there are multiple posts on this type of error and I tried to implement anything but I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get this error when you try to add the same instance of the view which is already added and attached previously to the parent view.

Since it is working for the first as expected.  you have to create new views whenever onClick is pressed. So better you move the below lines of code to onClick and try

```
createEvent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

           final LinearLayout layoutNewEvent = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
            final LinearLayout linearLayoutEventText = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
            final LinearLayout linearLayoutEventIndicator = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
            final LinearLayout linearLayoutEventVoyage = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
            final ImageView imageViewEventFrom = new ImageView(getActivity());
            final ImageView imageViewEventTo = new ImageView(getActivity());
            final ImageView imageViewSearch = new ImageView(getActivity());
            final TextView textViewEventTo = new TextView(getActivity());
            final TextView textViewEventFrom = new TextView(getActivity());
            i++
            .
            .
            .
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to add a view that already exists.

```
 eventLayout.addView(layoutNewEvent, layoutNewEventParams);
```

you should create a new view

```
LinearLayout newView = new LinearLayout(context);
```

Comment: Can ask you how exactly shall I go about it ?